# Which answer to pick when you have - Actual Answer VS Method

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Excuse me for my unclear question title, math terms have never been my forté. However being new here and knowing I shall be staying here for a while, I thought it's best to do things right with the community and site.

I just asked my first [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920192/differentiation-with-respect-to-variable) here and got a great response and nice welcome. However I have no idea which *answer* I, as a community member should pick.

The reason being is that the first one explains how to get there *(which is something I requested in the question itself)* whilst the other one is the actual answer to the questions but doesn't directly tell me how he got there even though he did somewhat clarify that in the comments.

A general rule of thumb for such scenarios would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: related questions: [one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12458/8348), [two](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11985/8348), [three](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9728/8348), [four](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/7131/8348), [five](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6184/8348)

Comment: @Arthur: I like my comment on the second link. I think it's one of the most helpful things I've written on this site! :P

Comment: And what if a *third* answer is posted, which unequivocally outshines those two? After all, 35 minutes is not such a long time span...

Comment: @Did Then I presume the third answer should be the ticked one, am I correct?

Comment: ...Which seems to hint (not so) subtly that other time frames than the one you used there, might have some virtues.

Comment: And if someone deemed the question was still left partially unanswered and wishes to include a full-blown answer, I would gladly mark their answer as the correct one.

Comment: I think that @Did was trying to point out that it's usually a good idea to give some time between posting a question to accepting an answer. Several hours at least (unless the answer is incredibly complete, or something like that).

Comment: Alright then, I shall do so

Comment: Just pick whatever answer which will help you to solve next similar question you see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick the one that has been the most helpful.

Remember the old saying, give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach him how to fish, and you'll be taking parts in destroying our oceans.

Comment: Very good point, thanks!

Comment: The saying in your post leaves me speechless... :-)

Comment: @Did: Well, you know... give a man a word, and you'll hear him for a day; teach him how to speak and you'll never hear the end of it!

Answer (score 4):

I have answered this question three times before. So rather than repeating myself, I'll direct you to my previous answers.

- [Is it rude to change which answer you accept?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/is-it-rude-to-change-which-answer-you-accept/2784#2784)
- [How do you accept the right answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7131/how-do-you-accept-the-right-answer/7133#7133)
- [What factors should be considered to accept an answer: Time, completeness or what?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656/what-factors-should-be-considered-to-accept-an-answer-time-completeness-or-wha/3657#3657)